# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'

Tags: angular

I know there are a few other similar questions. I have already imported the `CommonModule` and `BrowserModule`. Still not able to fix the issue.

I'm facing the following error in the browser console due to ngFor.
[image: error in console]

**adduser.component.html**

```
<div class="ui segment">
 <ul>
   <li *ngFor="let role of userRoles">{{ role.role }}</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

**adduser.component.ts**

```
userRoles = [
{
  id: '1',
  role: 'Admin',
},
{
  id: '2',
  role: 'Advanced Customer',
},
{
  id: '3',
  role: 'Advanced staff',
},
{
  id: '4',
  role: 'Basic Staff',
},
{
  id: '5',
  role: 'Tenant',
},
];
```

**users.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { UsersRoutingModule } from './users-routing.module';
import { AdduserComponent } from './adduser/adduser.component';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [AdduserComponent],
 imports: [CommonModule, UsersRoutingModule],
 exports: [AdduserComponent],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

 @NgModule({
 declarations: [AppComponent],
 imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AdduserComponent } from './users/adduser/adduser.component';

 const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'users', component: 
 AdduserComponent }];

 @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
 })
 export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Hey, can you add your AppRoutingModule's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CommonModule` is correctly imported in `UsersModule`.
However this module is never used.

As it includes a dedicated routing module, it feels like the goal was to lazy load this module.

The `AppRoutingModule` route should be changed to:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'users', loadChildren: () => import(/* path to the UsersModule */).then(m => m.UsersModule}
];
```

Comment: Got it. It works now. So we have to lazy load the module if we have a dedicated routing file added for the module? Can't we eager load the module from the app routing file if it has its own routing file?

Comment: You don't have to lazy load it by having a dedicated routing file: you have to lazy load it if you want your UsersModule to be consumed. Otherwise, with your first try UsersModule is unknown: nothing is referencing it in your code (besides its own declaration).

Comment: If you just want to load your component eagerly, just get rid of the UsersModule and add your component to your AppModule.

Comment: What I got to know is that I didn't import the UsersModule in the AppModule. That's why the issue was occurring. With lazy load syntax I imported the UsersModule and it worked.

So It was simple, I imported the UsersModule into the AppModule and now it's working. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: If you stick with your former route definition, i would encourage you to delete the UsrrsModule and declares your component in AppModule directly: if you remove the requirement of lazy loading, you don't need the UserRoutingModule anymore and CommonModule content will be provided by BrowserModule in AppModule.